# is there any way to convert uicolor to int value?

Tags: objective-c, int, uicolor

I am trying to implement flood fill algorithm in my app.I got some code from GitHub.In that i need to pass target color and replacement colors in the form of int.
I tried as follows ,

```
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
 NSLog(@"colors original is %f %f %f %f",components[0],components[1], components[2], components[3]);
NSLog(@"original color is %d",[colorAsString intValue]);
UIColor *targetColor=[UIColor redColor];
const CGFloat *target = CGColorGetComponents(targetColor.CGColor);
NSString *colorAstarget = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", target[0], target[1], target[2], target[3]];
NSLog(@"colors target is %f %f %f %f",target[0], target[1], target[2], target[3]);

NSLog(@"target color is %d",[colorAstarget intValue]);
```

But am getting both as 1 in the NSLogs so that flood fill returning 0.
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: What are you expect int look like? Ex, For red 100 ? blue 1 ?

Comment: the entire color should be in int.bcz am passing this int as a color to the function